# EntityFrameworkCore - filter existing data with recieving object from http body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, rest, http-get

I have a .net core web API with some models from the database. in my Person table controller, I want the ability of filtering data with multiple fields.
for example: user who uses the API for receiving service, wants to see information of a person with some conditions. eg:{ a person who has -> gender=1 and code=2675 and enable=1 and ismarried=0}
for now, i can filter all persons from database, based on each property seperately. i receive the column name from header and then use a switch to check it.
like this:

```
// GET: api/Person/get
    [HttpGet("get")]
    public ActionResult GetPerson_id()
    {            
        try
        {               
            List<Person> Person = new List<Person>();

            string headerValue_Key = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Key"].ToString();
            if (headerValue_Key.Any() == false || string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue_Key) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue_Key)) return BadRequest("ERROR:Incorrect Header Value (Empty or Null 'Key')"); //401

            var headerValue_Value = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Value"];
            if (headerValue_Value.Any() == false || string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue_Value) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue_Value)) return BadRequest("ERROR:Incorrect Header Value (Empty or Null 'Value')"); //401               

            switch (headerValue_Key)
            {
                case "id":
                    Person = _context.People.Where(p => p.Id == Int32.Parse(headerValue_Value.ToString())).ToList();
                    break;
                case "firstname":                        
                    string header = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Array.ConvertAll(Regex.Unescape(headerValue_Value.ToString()).ToCharArray(), c => (byte)c));
                    Person = _context.People.Where(p => p.Firstname == header && p.Status == true).ToList();
                    break;                    
                case "code":
                    Person = _context.People.Where(p => p.Code == headerValue_Value.ToString() && p.Status == true).ToList();
                    break;
                case "gender":
                    Person = _context.People.Where(p => p.Gender == bool.Parse(headerValue_Value.ToString()) && p.Status == true).ToList();
                    break;
                case "mstatus":
                    Person = _context.People.Where(p => p.IsMarried == bool.Parse(headerValue_Value.ToString()) && p.Status == true).ToList();
                    break;
                case "military":
                    Person = _context.People.Where(p => p.MilitaryStatus == Int16.Parse(headerValue_Value.ToString()) && p.Status == true).ToList();
                    break;
                default:
                    return BadRequest("Key is not valid");
            }

            if (Person.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(Person);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

but with this, i cannot filter a person with 2 or more property at the same time.
i've been looking for a convenient way to do that.
i'm wondering if there is a way to get a json string or a Person object from body, like this:

```
public ActionResult GetPerson_id([FromBody] string filter)
```

or this:

```
public ActionResult GetPerson_id([FromBody] Person filter)
```

and find a person with needed data.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class GetPersonVm
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string Code {get; set;}
   public bool Gender {get;set;}
   public bool IsMarried {get;set;}
   public int MilitaryStatus {get;set;}
}
```

Instead of using **[FromBody]**, you can do it using **[FromQuery]**

```
// GET: api/Person/get
[HttpGet("get")]
public ActionResult GetPerson_id(FromQuery] GetPersonVm filter)
{            
    try
    {               
        var result = _context.People
                          .Where(p => p.Id == filter.Id 
                                   && p.FirstName == filter.FirstName
                                   && p.Code == filter.Code
                                   && p.Gender == filter.Gender
                                   && p.IsMarried == filter.IsMarried
                                   && p.MilitaryStatus == filter.MilitaryStatus
                                   && p.Status == true).ToList();
      
        if (result.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Ok(e.Message);
    }
}
```

If you want to make the **fields optional**, change the view model to the following

```
public class GetPersonVm
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string Code {get; set;}
   public bool? Gender {get;set;}
   public bool? IsMarried {get;set;}
   public int? MilitaryStatus {get;set;}
}
```

And your filter query to the following

```
var result = _context.People
            .Where(p => p.Id == filter.Id 
               && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.FirstName) || p.FirstName == filter.FirstName)
               && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Code) || p.Code == filter.Code)
               && (filter.Gender == null || p.Gender == filter.Gender)
               && (filter.IsMarried == null || p.IsMarried == filter.IsMarried)
               && (filter.MilitaryStatus == null || p.MilitaryStatus == filter.MilitaryStatus)
               && p.Status == true).ToList();
```